# Conditional formatting with the icon set and a formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting, excel-2011

Basically I am trying to use the conditional formatting icon set that is a green dot, orange dot and red dot.

If my value is smaller than my formulas value, display the green dot.

If my value is equal to my formulas value, display the orange dot.

If my value is more than my formulas value, display the red dot.

This is the EXACT formula I am trying to use:

```
VLOOKUP(product_ID,product_db,3,FALSE)
```

`product_ID` is the cell next to the cell I am trying to apply the conditional formatting to. `product_db` is a large table within another worksheet.

Although, when I am trying to use this, the formatting is not applied to my cell at all. No dots are displayed.

I believe it is because of my formula. Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

Here are some screen shots of what is happening:

Here is the quantity before the conditioning:

[image]

Here is the conditioning with the formula being: `=VLOOKUP(invoice_product,PRODUCT_DATABASE,3,FALSE)`

[image]

The quantity is then the EXACT same as the first image, unchanged. The value that my formula should return is 2, hence the orange dot should be displayed.

Comment: Since this is really about standard Excel features, I think this would be more appropriate to ask at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).  See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22922/which-site-do-excel-or-other-spreadsheet-formulas-belong-on) for some rationale.

Comment: Did you put an `=` before the formula?

Comment: @JamesL. - Tried with and without the `=`, although still no luck. My VLOOKUP function is definitely correct since I have tried it out in a blank cell and it is returning the correct value.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: That's an old thread. The current one now suggests that it can remain in SO. See [THIS](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199823/slight-amendment-to-close-reason)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Fair enough. I'm actually interested in the OP's question, but if it were me asking, I would still have asked at SU. Especially considering the conditional formatting is really what's at question here.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: True but since the OP is using formulas in conditional formatting and community thinks that formula is "Code" what can I say? Damn! I got heavily down voted for that :P

Comment: @fizzix: Can you show us an example screenshot?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'm just saying, one `VLOOKUP()` doesn't make this much more of a programming question than including the word `"if"` in a sentence. The real question here is about getting conditional formatting working (which in this case uses formulas). I've retracted my close vote, but I still think it would be more beneficial for the OP and the community at SU.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Added an edit to my question with some more details.

Comment: @fizzix - What is the range that the conditional formatting rule is applied to?  Does it include the cell with the value `2` in it (in the **Quantity** column)?

Comment: @fizzix: you are using Excel 2011?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Yes, Mac Excel 2011

Comment: @JamesL. - The conditional formatting is only applied to the cell with the `2` in it, being the 'Quantity' column. The `invoice_product` is referring to the cell next to it which has the products ID. The VLOOKUP function should return the number `2` since the VLOOKUP is referring to another worksheet

Comment: @SiddharthRout - You may need to elaborate a little more. Not really to sure what you both mean.

Comment: I don't have MAC with me at the moment so I will use some screenshots from Excel 2010 to demonstrate what I mean.. Bare with me for few minutes

Comment: @SiddharthRout - Thanks. Will stand by.

Comment: I created an example in Excel 2010 (Win) that approximates what you describe/show -- and it works.

Comment: @JamesL. - Anywhere that I could upload my file so that you could take a quick glance at it?

Comment: @fizzix - Sorry, I don't have a public location for file uploads.  Take a look at my answer and see if there is perhaps something you need to tweak in your workbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your conditional formatting formula included a range for the first parameter of the `VLOOKUP` formula.  You can't do that, it must be a single cell.  You can use an `INDIRECT` function to resolve the cell to the immediate left of the one in the quantity column.  Look at the following screen shot.  Also, because you are using icons as the conditional formatting, you cannot apply it to a range, it must be a single cell for the `INDIRECT` function in the `VLOOKUP` formula to work.  You could apply it to a range if you simply formatted the color of the text, but not when using icons.  Follow the instructions in the image:

[image: Image of Solution]

Comment: I'll test mine out and then let you know how it goes. Thanks

Comment: Did you verify that the cell format for the cell with the `2` and the format of the value returned from the `VLOOKUP` function are the same format?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help, was very challenging haha :)